# jQuery Nested Array..get immediate parent id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array

```
array = [
{
    "id": "67",
    "sub": [
        {
            "id": "663",
        },
        {
            "id": "435",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "546",
    "sub": [
        {
            "id": "23",
            "sub": [
             {
                 "id": "4",
             }
         ]
        },
        {
            "id": "71"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I am currently looping throught the array as follows

calling the array:

```
processArray(array);
```

the function loop

```
function processArray(arr)
{
    for(var item in arr) {
        var value = arr[item];      
        var order = item;
        var itemID = value.id;

        if(itemID != null)
        {
            $('.text').append(" ORDER : " + order + " Item ID : " + itemID  + "<br />" );
        }
        if(typeof(value) == 'object') { //If it is an array,            
            processArray(arr[item]);
        }
    }   
}
```

Currently i am getting the order of the item and the current ID no problem.  What i need however (for my database schema) is for each item get the ID of its parent if there is one.
Do i need to pass the parent to each node?  Or is there an easier way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r9frZ/)

Include an optional parameter `parentID` in the function; by doing this, you can still use the `processArray(array);` syntax to process the original array.

```
function processArray(arr, parentID)
{
    for(var item in arr) {
        var value = arr[item];      
        var order = item;
        var itemID = value.id;

        if(itemID != null)
        {
            var output = " ORDER : " + order + " Item ID : " + itemID;

            if( parentID ) { output += " PARENT : " + parentID; }

            $('.text').append( output + "<br />");
        }

        // PROCESS SUB-ARRAY
        if( typeof(value.sub) == 'object') { //If it is an array,            
            processArray( value.sub, itemID );
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi there, this never shows the parent item value just the standard items.

Comment: @user257503 Sorry, extra `+` sign lol...I've included a working demo

Answer (score 1):

Use an auxiliary function that has `id` as part of its signature:

```
function processArray(arr) {

    function _processArray(arr, id) {
        for (var item in arr) {

            var value = arr[item];
            var order = item;
            var itemID = value.id; // you need to change this because on the second call you pass in a string and not just an object
            var parentId = id;

            // Commenting the if statement that you had here actually shows the parent id's now.
            $('.text').append(" ORDER : " + order + " Item ID : " + itemID + " Parent Id : " + parentId + "<br />");


            if (typeof value === "object") { //use instanceof,            
                _processArray(arr[item], itemID);
            }
        }
    }

    _processArray(arr, 0);
}
```

Comment: Hi..this only displays the first level of items and never shows the second level...?  never seen nested functions tho.

Comment: Oops. Misread your structure :). The `typeof` you had there earlier was correct!

Comment: I've added a comment as to what you need to fix. Running low on time :)

Comment: Thanks for this..i could not make the necessary changes that was required but i am sure you solution would be right.. The only reason why i have selected the other answer was because i could get it working in time>  Thank you kindly for your assistance!